# Create a plist file per item

Tags: iphone, nsarray, plist

Does anybody know how to create a plist file per item in an array, so for example I have an add button which lets me add an item, how can I create a plist per item added and how can I then retrieve it back to view the data?

Comment: I have tried to see if I can have a plist with 2 arrays. The top array and the array for the items. But that only solved a part of the problem.

Comment: You should include your partly functional code then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would include a PLIST in your app bundle and copy it (with a different name each time) to the documents directory as needed. Now that you have a working PLIST, it's as simple as reading your PLIST into a NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableArray, editing it, and writing the results back to the PLIST.